# Remove space after text string in a cell - excel

Tags: excel, format

Ive pasted a large list of data into column A in a excel sheet, all the data has come in with a space after the text ie. `'text '`, `'some more text '`..

I need to clear away this last space, as an approach i tried to find/replace all spaces, but that left me with a load of text strings like `'somemoretext'` as it also deleted all the spaces in between words, any idea how i should handle this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TRIM](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php)
In Microsoft Excel, the TRIM function returns a text value with the leading and trailing spaces removed.

Or you can still use Find and Replace option: Find `"text "` Replace `"text"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical approach:  check last character

```
(right(cell;1))

=IF(RIGHT(A3;1)=" ";LEFT(A3;LEN(A3)-1);A3)
```

If an space exists at the end, it will return the string -1 character (the space)
if there isn't a space, it will return the text without change

Comment: i learned the semicolon is a regional setting, this code worked for me when I changed the semicolons to comma!

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove leading and trailing spaces from column name with this method.

[Remove Leading and Trailing Whitespace from Excel Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793920/remove-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-excel-cells/46196244#46196244)

See my answer there.